# Windows XP Issue - Explorer Running Slow & Video Lagging when popups appear or adjusting volume

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, lag, acronis-trueimage

Hardware:
 Samsung SF310 Laptop
 Intel Core i5
 4Gb RAM
 Samsung Evo 840 SSD (250Gb)

Software: 
 I have reloaded an image using Acronis:
 Windows XP Professional SP3
 All relevant drivers for my Samsung laptop, plus some additional programs.

Almost everything is running perfectly, however there are a couple of specific issues:

1. Western Digital Passport Ultra 1Tb external hard drive issue: 
   When I access the external drive, some folders open quickly & one large folder opens very very slowly.

   I have tried running the external hard drive on another Windows XP laptop and all folders open quickly. 
   So I'm assuming the problem is not with the external hard drive.
2. Play videos using vlc or gom player:
   2A. 
   When I play videos and a popup appears on the system tray / notification area (located in bottom right side of the desktop) the video lags until I close the popup.

   2B.
   The video will also lag when I adjust the volume (when watching a video).
   Once the volume display/gui disappears then the video stops lagging.

Conclusion:
I think there is a software conflict somewhere, but I am not sure how to identify, or fix the problem.

Please can someone help me. :..(
Thank you.